# Slide Panel Layout - Why master pane move, when detail pane is opened ? how to stop it?

Tags: android

I am planning to use Sliding Panel Layout for one of my App. In master pane there is an image and in detail pane a list view is used. Issue is when detail pane (Listview) is opened (left to right) master pane (image) is also moved towards left. I need master pane should not be moved when sliding panel is opened. You my refer attached screen to understand this.

[image: See attached screen]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/MenuList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#101010"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_robot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/android_robot" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Comment: In above code somehow initial few lines are not appearing, these are given below <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

Answer (score 0):

Firstly sliding of a menu is not depend on XML file. You should check your Class of Main activity. As reference visit here http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer, but here I am talking about Sliding Panel Layout ( android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout ) not Navigation Drawer. Navigation Drawer is already being used in same application but I need Sliding Panel Layout so can add more functionality witin same activity.

Comment: Just set overlay attribute to true, and set the color of the panel to transparent.

Comment: You should change Linear Layout to Frame Layout(which panel layout you want to slide should be inside Frame Layout)  and set its background to a semi-transparent color.